# How are my links being clicked already?

Tags: goo.gl

Earlier today, I created a set of Goo.gl links that I embedded in a private Google Docs document. I have not shared the doc or the links with anyone. After coming back to Goo.gl a while later, I noticed that I had numbers in the click count. After inspecting them, they all came from different Google.com domains (.pl .br and normal .com). All but one of them did not show on the map.

How are my links being clicked? Do they get indexed by Google Search Engine like other links and are being clicked by bots?

Answer (score 2):

Your suspicion is probably correct: Google bot is following your links shortly after you created the short link.

It makes sense. You've just told Google about a genuine link. Google didn't need to spider the rest of the web to find it.

Of course, only Google can answer for sure.